# interactive_markers missing

Tags: ros, rviz, visualization-msgs, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I've installed ros via ubuntu synaptic and a second time from source code.
Both times, there is no interactive_markers package and the visualization_msgs directory doesn't contain any interactive_markers msgs, either.
In the ROS SVN repository are the missing files, if I checked it out manually.
But in rviz they don't appear.

I use Ubuntu 11.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10600/interactive_markers-missing/) by [minne](https://answers.ros.org/users/835/minne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

interactive_markers package is expected in ROS Electric (next version of ROS due in August). Current ROS release doesn't have that package. You should be able to install it from source using instructions on [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/interactive_markers#Installation_from_trunk).

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [minne](https://answers.ros.org/users/835/minne/) on 2011-07-14**:
Thank you! That helped me alot!